# Are there any unicode/wide chars that encode to multiple encoded characters

Tags: c, character-encoding, internationalization

Consider wctomb(), which takes a wide character and encodes to the currently selected character set. The glibc man page states that the output buffer should be MB_CUR_MAX, while the FreeBSD man page states the output buffer size should be MB_LEN_MAX. Which is correct here?

Are there any example wide char/encoding combinations where it takes multiple encoded characters to represent the wide char?

On a more general note, does MB_CUR_MAX refer to the max combined encoded char byte count to represent a wide char, or is it just representing the max byte count for any particular encoded char?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MB_CUR_MAX` is correct, but both are big enough. You might want to use `MB_LEN_MAX` if you want to avoid variable-length array declarations.

`MB_CUR_MAX` is the maximum number of bytes in a multibyte character in the *current locale*. `MB_LEN_MAX` is the maximum number of bytes in a character for *any supported locale*. Unlike `MB_CUR_MAX`, `MB_LEN_MAX` is a macro so it can be used in an array declaration without creating a VLA.

Both constants refer to a single wide character. There is no simple definition of what a multibyte character is exactly, since multibyte encodings can include shift sequences; if the multibyte locale includes shift sequences, the number of bytes required for a particular call to `wctomb` with a particular wide character might vary from call to call depending on the shift state. (Also, the actual code might be different in different shift states.)

As far as I know, there is nothing which prevents a wide character from being translated to a multibyte sequence which might be decomposable into other multibyte sequences (as with Unicode composition); the definition of `wctomb` talks only about "representation". But I don't know of an implementation which does that, either; Unicode canonical decomposition must be done with separate APIs.

So it is possible that no installed locale requires a value as large as `MB_LEN_MAX`. But there is nothing stopping you from adding locales -- or even creating your own -- provided that they don't exceed the encoding limit (16 bytes on Linux).

Comment: Yes I see the distinction between runtime and compile time constants, though am not convinced as to whether the these constants refer to a single encoded character. Let me ask a different way. If MB_LEN_MAX represents only a single encoded character, then what character in what encoding needs 16 bytes (which is the value on GNU/Linux)

Comment: @pixelbeat: There isn't one (that I know of), but you're allowed to create your own multibyte locales, provided that you do not define a character whose encoding would require more than 16 bytes. The constants refer to a single character. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I see that iso-2022-kr takes up to 7 bytes per char, and that's what made me suspect that MB_LEN_MAX might be so large to hold multiple chars (2 + alignment). By default on my Fedora 22 system, UTF8 has the largest MB_CUR_MAX at 6, with various other encodings taking 2,3 or 4 bytes. I'm still not sure why MB_LEN_MAX is so large.

Comment: I aksed Bruno Haible who anwered at http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnulib/2015-05/msg00001.html and essentially agreed with this answer. I.E. there is a 1:1 mapping between wide chars and encoded chars in POSIX and glibc, and MB_LEN_MAX=16 is for future proofing only

Comment: If some library thinks that "UTF8 has the largest MB_CUR_MAX at 6" then that's a bug. Valid UTF-8 can have max 4 bytes. A variant with up to 6 bytes is called "CESU" and "Such an encoding is not conformant to UTF-8 as defined". (see http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf8-4). The other way to go up to 6 bytes is if you represent characters beyond U+10FFFF, which is (again) invalid Unicode (http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#gen6)